# How to make a scroll view for table acquired from php array

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have this multidimensional array `$array2` which displays as follows
(This is just part of the array, it contains over 1000 elements)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => M2TYEE
            [1] => Jean
            [2] => Harvey
            [3] => London
            [4] => 0314686334
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => E26YBE
            [1] => Tom
            [2] => Cruise
            [3] => New York
            [4] => 0635625735     
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => M2FY3E
            [1] => Jane
            [2] => Harvey
            [3] => Berlin
            [4] => 0314346334
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q53YBE
            [1] => Tom
            [2] => Howland
            [3] => New York
            [4] => 0635625735     
        )
)
(This is just part of the array, it contains over 1000 elements)
```

I have managed to create a table out of it using the code

```
<?php
$arr = array_merge([ 0 => ['ID','FIRST NAME','LAST NAME','CITY','PHONE']],$array);
$html = '<table border="1">';
foreach($arr as $row){
  $html .= '<tr>';
  foreach($row as $column){
    $html .= '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
  }
  $html .= '</tr>'; 
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
?>
```

The above code displays all table records and what I **expected** was a scroll view table which displays only 10 records/rows.

Comment: do you need a scroll after 10 rows, so the table will only consume the space of 10 rows on the page?

Comment: Yes @RakeshJakhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DIV` and put the `table` inside the div for example :

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow:scroll;"> <!-- inline-css -->
 <?php echo $html;?>
</div>
```

`OR`

you can create a class in CSS

```
.overflow-div{
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

use this class in div

```
<div class="overflow-div">
 <?php echo $html;?>
</div>
```

You can put the `height` whatever you want.